# answer check for a calculus 3 variable chain rule problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

yo.

find $\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{t}} = ?$

$V =\frac{1}{3}{x^2}h$

$x = \frac{t}{t+1}$

$h = \frac{1}{t+1}$

---

$$\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{t}} = \frac{2t-t^2}{3(t+1)^4}$$

Does this look correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solve this problem is to plug $x, h$ into $V$. Then calculate the derivative.

So $V=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{t^2}{(t+1)^2}\cdot \frac{1}{(t+1)}$

Using quotient rule: $\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{2t\cdot 3(t+1)^3-9(t+1)^2\cdot t^2}{9(t+1)^6} = \frac{2t-t^2}{3(t+1)^4}$

So your answer is correct.

Comment: I appreciate it.

Comment: You should have used the chain rule.